# How to retrieve existing json from content-type text/html; charset=utf-8?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to retrieve existing json from the get call. I'm calling simple get for instagram page and while decoding to json I get

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

My code:

```
s = HTMLSession()
req = s.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
text = json.loads(req.content.decode("utf-8"))
print(text)
```

Comment: Apparently, the page didn't return a json for you.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I understand it is not pure json, but in the content reponse there is a json part and i was wondering if I could retrieve it somehow. I need to get some values and I would like to do it in simple way, avoiding string operations.

Comment: Could you declare the json you want?

Comment: You might want to use an existing instagram-scraper: https://pypi.org/project/instagram-scraper

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA it's named "config"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

text = req.json()
print(text)
```